# ADB2C built-in policies and javascript

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

ADB2C now allow us to use javascript within built-in policies.
But this is still a preview feature (since several months). Is it safe to use it or not ? We clearly need now to move on the new b2clogin.com domain and we would have taken the opportunity to also implement javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Pubic previews are not suggested for production environment because, the behavior will change during preview and we can't confirm the GA date.

Comment: This feature is in preview since almost 1 year. And is available for IEF policies since december 18. Can we imagine to have a GA soonly ? We really need it and be sure there won't be changes (isn't that the purpose of the contract pages?)

Comment: No ETA for now :-(